# onClientClick event

Tags: asp.net, javascript

when i used onClientClick event for calling a javascript function in .aspx file. but it's not working at all.how can i get alert for input of data within "<>" in textbox.
pls help me

Comment: Please post some code so we know what you are doing and what results to expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onClientClick="alert('picnic4u'); return false"
```